# Java RESTful Service - 404 Not Found

Tags: java, rest, http-status-code-404, restful-url

I am trying to create a RESTful Service in Java using Eclipse, but I have hardly ever worked with this types of projects and I'm getting quite lost trying to create the path of my service, always getting 404 Not Found.

This is my Java class `prueba.MyService.java`:

```
package prueba;
import ....
....

@Path("/service")
public class MyService{ 

    @Path("/hello")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello() {
       return "Hello World()";
    }

    ...
}
```

This is my `prueba.ApplicationConfig.java` class, in which I have added the `@ApplicationPath` annotation:

```
package prueba;

import ...
...

@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

     @Override
     public  Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
        classes.add(prueba.MyService.class);

        return classes;
     }

}
```

I have also tried to add the `<servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping>` tags in the `web.xml` file, but it didn't solve anything, and based on what I have read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24983/develop.htm#RESTF208), with the `@ApplicationPath` annotation should be enough.

After this, I run my service with an Apache Tomcat server and I try to access the **http://localhost:8080/rest/service/hello** URL, but I get the 404 Not Found error.

Sorry in advance if I am missing something really basic or stupid.

---

***Found the solution by myself:***

I have finally started all over again following [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/restful_first_application.htm) and now it works correctly. Hope it helps.